# distributed build system Linux for c++ (make is not fast enough in this case)

Tags: c++, linux, distributed, build-system

I am looking for a built system that I can distribute it over a cluster of multi-core CPUs (for speed-up purposes). I have big design in C/C++ and my platform is Linux (Red-Hat).
So these are the following measure that are important for me:

- runs in a distributed mode
- supports the use of multi-core
- scalable for big designs and incremental compiles/builds
- Fast
- Possibly open source.
- works under Linux

Comment: Doesn't `make -j` suit your needs? I'm not sure whether it can distribute work between clusters, but it does multithreading fine.

Comment: make is not fast enough for my design! please remove the duplicate flag @BaummitAugen

Comment: It is a duplicate. The linked question includes your question. Anyway, you could look at Incredibuild. It's good, but it costs money.